# MAX com LIMIT não dá o resultado correto

Tags: mysql, query, sql-select

Imaginem as seguintes linhas no meu banco de dados MySQL:

[image: Exemplo de dados da tabela]

Quero uma *query* que exiba o nome e a idade da pessoa que tem a maior idade na tabela, para isso fiz essa *query*:

```
SELECT nome, MAX(idade) 
from pessoas;
```

Porém ela não retorna o nome corretamente.

Preciso de uma solução que condiciona o nome a idade retornada pelo comando `MAX`, não queria uma subconsulta que compara se a idade com o `MAX(idade)` de outra consulta. Existe isso que eu preciso?

Comment: Que nome quer que retorne? O que está ocorrendo de errado? E por que não quer um subconsulta?

Comment: Não pode agrupar pelo nome?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

A subconsulta é a solução padrão e eu iria nela. Mas se quiser insistir em outra poderia ser esta (que pode ser pior):

```
SELECT nome, idade FROM pessoas ORDER BY idade DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Se não tiver um índice adequado poderá ser bem lento, claro, não mais lento que a subconsulta sob as mesmas condições. Não existe nada milagroso.

Se tiver empate em idade pegará um deles, provavelmente o primeiro que foi inserido, a pergunta não especifica critérios desempate ou se deve pegar todos da mesma idade, o que provocaria uma subconsulta de qualquer jeito.

Apenas para completeza da resposta, sei que não quer (não sei o motivo), mas para outros usuários que quiserem fazer a subconsulta.

```
SELECT nome, idade FROM pessoas WHERE idade = (SELECT MAX(idade) FROM pessoas);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/MaxAge.sql).

Answer (score 2):

Já apresentaram as melhores soluções. Mas dá para resolver apenas com junções seu problema:

```
SELECT a1.nome, a1.idade
FROM pessoas a1 LEFT JOIN
    pessoas a2 on a1.idade < a2.idade
WHERE a2.idade IS NULL
```

Peguei a ideia [de um `LEFT JOIN WITH EXCLUSION`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118352/64969). A ideia geral daqui é:

- pegue todas as pessoas e, associadas a elas, pessoas mais velhas
- remova todos os pares em quem se conseguiu determinar alguém mais velho

Não sei o impacto de performance dessa solução, mas teve casos em que foi mais fácil usá-la do que tentar um subselect aqui no trabalho. Use com parcimônia e sabedoria, entretanto.

Answer (score 1):

É que quando você atribui uma coluna MAX(idade) ela trará apenas a maior idade da coluna idade em todas as linhas da pesquisa.

Seguindo a linha da resposta do Maniero, você pode selecionar apenas um registro da pessoa com maior idade (mas você pode ter outros com a mesma idade no banco):

```
SELECT nome, idade FROM pessoas ORDER BY idade DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Ou então, usar uma subconsulta, que poderá ser bem mais lento, mas trará todos os registros dos que tiverem a maior idade cadastrada:

```
SELECT nome, idade FROM pessoas WHERE idade = (SELECT MAX(idade) FROM pessoas) ORDER BY nome ASC;
```

E como ele mesmo citou, é importante que você tenha um índice que contenha os campos que você utiliza na sua consulta, nesse caso um índice que tenha idade e nome poderia ser bem interessante, pois você poderia consultar nome e idade trazendo apenas todos que tem maior idade e ordenando por nome.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
SELECT nome, idade from pessoas WHERE idade = ( select max( idade ) from pessoas )
```